# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification(Mixing version can lead to run time crashes)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have updated android studio to 2.3.
I have searched and applied all the solutions given on this forum but my problem still not solved. 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
         This library dependency show error

```
//Here is my build.gradle file

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.compass.islamicdirection"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.5.2.jar')
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'`

First you need to check your SDK Manager has all latest google package installed in extras folder. Then, build your project again if still the error occurs then only use those play services which are needed by you like location, ads, etc.

Do not use full google play services if you want to use only the location api. Also, this issue occurs with several different libraries.

Comment: One Thing more i want to integrate adobe creative sdk.
Still Same error Occure.
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
    compile "com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4"
    compile "com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0"}

Comment: after 2.5 hours I find this answer. My only problem if I exclude play services but my dependency module (3rd party SDK) is using that, is it still going to work?

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem, change the version 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'

to this: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'

25.0.2 is your buildToolsVersion.

Comment: That does not work and really has nothing to do with the question, at least in most cases. The answer above has helped most but in my case, it seems that Android Studio 2.3 was looking for Support v13 version 25.1.1, even though 25.3.0 is installed. It could simply be an error with Android Studio itself.